# lex flex scanner with multiple buffers

Tags: lex

I want to use the yy_scan_bytes() as I have null characters defining a rule. My problem is that my string can match more than one rule. I want to get hold of all the rules matched. I want to feed the yylex() function one character at a time and check if something matched. I tried the following code for testing but this doesnt work.

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    yy_scan_bytes(&temp[i],1 );
    index=TomsonTalkslex();
}
```

For simplicity I just return the index of the rule matched from scanner. temp is a char buffer. I tried to use the yy_switch_to_buffer(yy_scan_bytes(&temp[i],1 )); but this didnt work.

How can I tell the scanner not to reset its state and continue processing subsequent buffers with the same state.

Comment: Why do you need to use scan bytes? By default, yylex reads input a character at a time until EOF, so null bytes should read fine. Also, do you want to save the current buffer state for when you use this buffer later, or keep the state while you switch buffers using *your last buffer state with your new buffer*?

Comment: I have my data input at runtime, so I need to use scan bytes. Also I want to call yylex for each character, I dont want it to reset its state machine, thats why I want to save the buffer state. I want to use my last buffer state with the new buffer. For eample I have 2 rules, one for matching ab and another for marching cd. If I input "abcd" to scan bytes it will return only one match which I think would be cd. I want both the rules, I want ab rule when ab is processed, and cd when cd is processed, and this can only be done through scan bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, This is just a misunderstanding of how lex/flex works. By default, yylex hooks into stdin, reading until it receives EOF, and matching each rule. That's why it's a tokenizer. So, the sample program below will read from stdin until you enter -c to send an EOF.

```
%option 8bit outfile="scanner.c"
%option nounput nomain noyywrap
%option warn

%%

ab { fprintf(yyout, "We ran the ab rule.\n"); }
cd { fprintf(yyout, "We ran the cd rule.\n"); }

    // echo everything else we find to yyout
. { ECHO; }
\n { ECHO; }

%%
```

To compile the above, use:

```
flex -Cf scanner.l 
gcc -O -o flexer.exe scanner.c
```

Save the source file as scanner.l when you do this. Once you compile, you will get a file called flexer.exe in the same directory. Run it from a terminal, and you will get a blank prompt waiting for input. Everything you type will try and match against the rules, until you find only one match. It will then execute the code associated with the rule.

Therefore, if you type `abcd`, then you will match both the `ab` and `cd` rules.

I suggest reading [lex and yacc](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do) for a more detailed introduction.

Comment: Well I really want to do the same but dont want to use stdin, I want to do it with scan bytes. I have tried a lot of things from the lex and yacc manual but none is working for scan bytes. I want to call scan bytes as given in the code in my original post.

Comment: @Saba [The flex manual](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html#Multiple-Input-Buffers) indicates that yy_scan_bytes switches to a newly created buffer on each call. I don't think it will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, is there any other way to do what I want, but I want to use in memory buffer :(

Comment: @saba You can change where you are reading from by setting `yyin` before you call `yylex()`. If your lexer has rules in it to return from lexing, it leaves everything "paused". You can then add to the buffer that you pointed `yyin` to, and call `yylex()` again to start back up, with more stuff in the buffer. You don't need to use `yy_scan_bytes`. You don't want to change buffers, you just want to append more data to the current buffer.